# A proof of Holder continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, holder-spaces

I'm studying the following proof by I'm not able to understand the main step.
Let
\begin{equation}
\sigma(x)=\sqrt{\beta x(N-x)+\alpha x}
\end{equation}
defined for $x \in [0, N+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}]$. I want to prove that there exist a constant $L > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
|\sigma(x)-\sigma(y)| \le L \sqrt{|x-y|} \quad \forall x \in [0, N+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}]
\end{equation}
The proof the I'm studying works as follow:

choose $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{4}(N+\frac{\alpha}{\beta})$, and consider separately the regions 
\begin{align}\varepsilon &\le x \le N+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}- \varepsilon, \quad \varepsilon \le y \le N+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}- \varepsilon \\ 
0 & \le x,y \le \varepsilon\\ 
N& +\frac{\alpha}{\beta}- \varepsilon \le x,y \le N+\frac{\alpha}{\beta},\\  N& +\frac{\alpha}{\beta}- \varepsilon <x \le N+\frac{\alpha}{\beta},\quad  0<y<\varepsilon  \\ 0&<x<\varepsilon,\quad N +\frac{\alpha}{\beta}- \varepsilon <y < N+\frac{\alpha}{\beta} 
\end{align} Then it is straightforward to show that the previous relation holds.

But why holds? what is the problem in the original domain?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Do you have an argument that works directly when considering $x,y$ in the original domain? Are you asking for an explanation why a direct approach won't work when $x,y$ are in the original domain?

Comment: @AhmedHussein I'll try to explain better...I have to prove that there exist a  constant L such that.....Now, my problem is: why I have to take a partition like that of my domain? and if in that regions works, how can I conclude that it works for every $x,y$ in my domain? Hope to more clear than before...

Comment: It works since you too all the possible cases when $x,y$ are in that domain

Comment: @AhmedHussein okay, but why I have to divide the domain in this way? Why I can't consider the whole domain?

Comment: I simply think that this subdivision simplifies the estimates that will occur in the square root, and lets you control the inequalities in an easier way. That's basically all there is to it. Such subdivision are often used in geometric measure theory, for example when you divide a Ball in diadic annuli to better control the distance from the center